# How to remove Zopim Branding from its chat widget?

Tags: javascript, html, css, overriding

We are using Zopim Chat widget in our website but we want to remove Zopim branding from it.

Here is the link to the chat widget:

https://v2.zopim.com/widget/livechat.html?key=2C2a6X5hH4Hm4OgYGo90Qlg8hPfnggbK&mid=SKeHknBr5NNNqJ&lang=no&hostname=support.smspluss.no&api_calls=%5B%5D

How can we override Zopim CSS?
How can we remove Zopim from the bottom of the page? 
Also how to change the Favi Icon?

Comment: Pay for a licence - https://www.zopim.com/pricing

Comment: Since you're suing the free version, show some appreciation by leaving the bran name as it is.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you value the product Zopim delivers. Altering the code behind the chat client is against their TOS. If you want a white-label chat client, please consider buying it.

I'm being polite here but this frustrates me a bit.

If you're working with .Net, please check SingalR to create your own chat client. (Yes, I know it's very simple and that it implies a few external dependencies.)

TL;DR: "Buy it, or leave it."

Regards,
Eddie